# electron builded exe app - generating file (unpacked - ok / portable - nothing) - why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, exceljs

I wrote an electron app which parse different info from sites/ this script works in main process w/o executeJavascript but as imported module. main process send messages to renderer which url did loaded and the final message - done. it works in both cases (unpacked/portable). file generated is the xlsx. lib is exseljs.

workbook.xlsx.writeFile(`../${title}.xlsx`);

[app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f183e.png)

[dist folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU0xD.png)

Comment: Do not post images! It is better to either explain or sketch the file structure or anything else represented on the image because links can die and then the question has no meaning.

Comment: I hope it is also clearly written without pictures?